# Custom Walker_Nav_Menu issue with variables on PHP 7.3

Tags: php, menus, navigation, walker

I've made this custom walker that extends Walker_Nav_Menu for "mega menu" implementation. It works perfectly fine from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7.2, however it it has problems on PHP 7.3. The idea is to compare ID of menu element in start_lvl and end_lvl to see if the megamenu div should be closed, on PHP7.3 those IDs match themselves once in a while, you can refresh site few times and it will work once and the 10 next times it won't.

```
class custom_theme_megamenu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
   /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     */
    var $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var array
     */
    var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

    //save current item so it can be used in start level
    private $curItem;
    private $curLvl;
    private $megamenu;
    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     */
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
          $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

            $megamenu = get_post_meta( $this->curItem->ID, '_menu-item-megamenu', true);
            $megamenu_width = get_post_meta( $this->curItem->ID, '_menu-item-columns', true);

            if($depth === 1) {

                $tag = "ul";
            } else {
                $tag = "ul";
            }

            if($megamenu) {

                $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"mega-menu mobile-styles ".$megamenu_width." \"><ul>\n";  
            } else {
                $output .= "\n$indent<".$tag." class=\"sub-menu \">\n";
            }

    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     */
    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

            $megamenu = get_post_meta( $this->curItem->ID, '_menu-item-megamenu', true);

            if($depth === 1) {

                if($megamenu) {

                    $output .= "\n$indent</ul>\n";
                } else {
                    $output .= "\n$indent</ul>\n";
                }
            } else {
               if($megamenu) {
                    $output .= "\n$indent</ul>\n";
                } else {
                    $output .= "\n$indent</ul>\n";
                }
            }

    }

    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     * @param int    $id     Current item ID.
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        //save current item to private curItem to use it in start_lvl
        $this->curItem = $item;

        $class_names = '';
        $this->megamenu = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu-item-megamenu', true);
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        $classes[] = 'parentid'.get_post_meta( $item->ID,  '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true);
        /**
         * Filter the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's <li>.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @see wp_nav_menu()
         *
         * @param array  $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's <li>.
         * @param object $item    The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args    An array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $hiddenstatus = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu-item-hiddenonmobile', true);
        if($hiddenstatus == 'hide') {
            $classes[] = 'hidden-on-mobile';
        }
        $classes[] = 'depth'.$depth;
        if($depth === 0 && $this->megamenu != '') {
            $classes[] = 'has-megamenu';
        } else {
            $classes[] = 'dropdown';
        }

        if($depth === 1) {
            $parent = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true);
            $parent_has_megamenu = get_post_meta( $parent, '_menu-item-megamenu', true);

            if ($parent_has_megamenu == '_blank') {

                $widthclass = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu-item-columns', true);
                $classes[] =  $widthclass;
            }

        }
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filter the ID applied to a menu item's <li>.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         *
         * @see wp_nav_menu()
         *
         * @param string $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's <li>.
         * @param object $item    The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args    An array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';


        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        /**
         * Filter the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's <a>.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         *
         * @see wp_nav_menu()
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's <a>, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
         * }
         * @param object $item The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args An array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );
        $is_clickable = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'link_disabled', true);
        $jsarg = ($is_clickable == '1') ? 'onclick="return false;"' : '';
        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }
        $linkrole = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu-item-linkrole', true);

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $icon = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu-item-icon', true); 
        if(!empty($icon)){
            if(substr($icon,0, 2) == 'ln'){
                $icon = '<i class="'.esc_attr($icon).'"></i> ';
            } else {
                  $icon = '<i class=" sl sl-icon-'.esc_attr($icon).'"></i> ';
            }

        }
        if($depth === 1 ) {
            if($linkrole == 'title' ) {
                $item_output .= $args->link_before .'<span class="mega-menu-headline">'.$icon. apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) .'</span>'. $args->link_after;
            } elseif($linkrole == 'paragraph') {
                $content = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu-item-html', true);
                $item_output .= '<p>';
                $item_output .= $args->link_before;
                $item_output .= do_shortcode($content);
                $item_output .= $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= '</p>';
            } elseif($linkrole == 'paragraphtitle') {
                $content = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu-item-html', true);
                $item_output .= '<p>';
                $item_output .= $args->link_before .'<span class="mega-menu-headline"">'.$icon. apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) .'</span>';
                $item_output .= do_shortcode($content);
                $item_output .= $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= '</p>';
            } else if($linkrole == 'hidden') {

            } else {
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' '.$jsarg.'>';
                $item_output .= $args->link_before .$icon. apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= '</a>';
            }
        } elseif( $depth === 0 ) {
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' '.$jsarg.'>';
                $item_output .= $args->link_before .$icon. apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= '</a>';
        } else {
                $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' '.$jsarg.'>';
                $item_output .= $args->link_before .$icon. apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= '</a>';
        }


    /*    if($depth === 0 && $this->megamenu != '') {
            $item_output .= '<div class="mega two-cols">
                            <div class="mega-section">';
        }*/

        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filter a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes $args->before, the opening <a>,
         * the menu item's title, the closing </a>, and $args->after. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing <li> for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @see wp_nav_menu()
         *
         * @param string $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param object $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int    $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array  $args        An array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     */
    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        $this->megamenu = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu-item-megamenu', true);
        if($depth === 0 && $this->megamenu != '') {
            $output .= "</div>\n";
        } else {
         $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
    }

}
```

I try to assign the $curItem to know which elements holds the megemenu, and on which end_lvl it ends to be able to close it correctly (megamenu is in div instead of ul). on PHP 7.3 it randomly works, once in few tries the variable matches, but in most cases it looks like it doesn't assign it correctly. Can anyone point me what has changed in PHP 7.3 that could affect it?

Thanks

EDIT: full class https://pastebin.com/pKFmi7LT

Comment: Hi, what are you using `CurLvl` and `megamenu` private fields for? And how do you set the `_menu-item-megamenu` post meta? Is this meta set for posts or for menu items?

Comment: The code won't "randomly work" unless you keep changing things! It either works or it won't. Do you see any errors in your `error.log` file? Turn on `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` as well.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż those are set as menu items meta, the curLvl is actually not used, it's leftover from previous iteration of the code. I use only $curItem, my idea is that if the menu item has post meta '_menu-item-megamenu' it starts the menu with <div class="mega-menu"> instead of standard "<ul>". The problem is that in the end_lvl I need to know if I'm still with the same ID that start_lvl was. It works perfectly fine on PHP 7.2, but in PHP 7.3 it works once in few times, like the ID in end_lvl is different each time and just sometimes match the start_lvl

Comment: full class is https://pastebin.com/pKFmi7LT , there are no errors in error.log

Comment: @rzepak Are you using a plugin for the mega menu implementation?

Comment: @rzepak Maybe not the solution, but you have an undefined variable `$allowed_html_array` on line 537.

Comment: @rzepak Also, when developing things like that, if you are not that familiar with the PHP debugging, I would always highly recommend installing and using the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin! It will light up if you have any errors or warnings in your PHP code, and is useful for so many things!

Comment: The way you're hijacking `start_el()` in `my_theme_walker_nav_edit` from the full class made me stop reviewing the code. There's a lot going on that's not best practice that can't be answered fully in this setting.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett anything you can point me to what's wrong there?